# Discover Whether A Program Is Installed From Python3 Script

Tags: python, git

Within my python3 software I need to check to see if git is installed. I know that from the terminal I can type:

```
dpkg --get-selections > filename
```

to find what programs are installed and then put that into a file.

From there, how would I get python to see if git is installed? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Using the terminal command and putting it into a file doesn't work, as if you uninstall a program the file is still there but just has the word "deinstalled" on the same line instead of "installed".

Comment: To stick with a terminal command but do it a lot easier, you can do: "dpkg -s git". You'll get the package details if it's installed or "Package `git' is not installed and no info is available" if it's not installed.

Answer (score 5):

You may use the python apt module, but it only checks if the package is installed. It will fail non-deb distributions or if installed outside the package manager:

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
cache.open()
 cache["git-core"].is_installed# Evaluates true if git is installed
```

Try to run git and handle the exception if it fails:

```
import subprocess

try:
    # pipe output to /dev/null for silence
    null = open("/dev/null", "w")
    subprocess.Popen("git", stdout=null, stderr=null)
    null.close()

except OSError:
    print("git not found")
```

A third option would be to try all the paths in `$PATH` and test if you have exec permission on path/git.

Comment: If you use `subprocess.DEVNULL` instead of the dev device, this answer works on Windows CPython too.

`git_found = subprocess.call(['git', '--version'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL) != 0
`

Answer (score 2):

### Look for installed files

Assuming we know where the application's launcher or binary is installed by default an easy to do approach would be to just check for it's existence like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#
# Query package state by installation path

import os.path
path = '/usr/bin/git'


def query_package(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print('Git is ready to use')
    else:
        print('please install Git')
```

### Consult DPKG

Another way to query installed packages however is to consult the package management, in our case dpkg:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#
# Query package state by dpkg status

import subprocess
package = 'git'

def query_package(package):
    status = subprocess.getstatusoutput("dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' " + package)
    if not status[0]:
        print(status[1]) # package is installed
    else:
        print(status[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it that way you could do something like:

```
checkvar = 0  
for line in open("filename"):  
    if "git" in line:  
        checkvar = checkvar + 1  
print "Phrase git found ", checkvar, " times"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach. In order to check whether Git is available on a given system, either check if the `git` binary exist in user's PATH, or just try to execute `git --version`. This check will be more reliable, and it supports people who (for any reason) install Git from source in /usr/local/bin, or even ~/bin.

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I hope it helps anyway. If you need a help in coding that in Python, let me know and I'll provide more details.

Comment: Seems reasonable, but how would I go about getting python to register whether or not git is actually there?

Comment: Try to run it with subprocess.Popen() and handle the exception if it fails. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try checking the output of `which`.

(Maybe that won't work as no one else has suggested it?)

Comment: `which` is a shell built-in, so you would have to spawn a shell first.

Comment: `/usr/bin/which` isn't a shell built-in, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Right, it's a built-in only in Zsh (which I use). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: As of 2022, use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module (which is awesome)! And here's the onliner:

```py
import subprocess; subprocess.run(["git", "--version"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, check=True)
```

### The `subprocess` Module:

The `subprocess` module is the epitome of all reasons why Python is an amazing scripting language! I use it for everything where a Shell script might end up being too unmaintainable & cluttered.

On that note, here's the update code snippet you should be using right now for Python v3.5+:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["git", "--version"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, check=True)
```

### The `subprocess.run()` Function is All You'll Ever Need:

Introduced in Python v3.5, the [`run()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is all you'll ever need to invoke a tool from a Python script. And in addition, it's `check` parameter will throw a [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) in case the process(es) exits with a non-zero code. Hence, you can easily check if a tool is installed or simply by passing `True` to the `check` parameter of the `run()` function.